# Updating MediaStore.Audio.Media columns not working on API 30+ ( Android 11)

Tags: java, android, mediastore

**Issue:**

Updating media files(audio) with `Contentresolver.update();` not working on Android 11.

`RecoverableSecurityException` is thrown and i ask for permission to modify the content

`Contentresolver.update()` returns 1 so the columns should be updated but after refreshing the app content goes back to the old values.

I queried the Uri (content://media/external/audio/media/47) too check the values of the columns i'm trying to update and they are still returning the old values for some reason.

Code works fine below Android 11.

**Code:**

```
public void changeMp3Tags(Context c, Uri musicUri,
                          String title, String artist, String album, String year) {
    try {
        //musicUri: content://media/external/audio/media/47
        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);

        ContentResolver resolver = c.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String titleColumn      = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
        String artistColumn     = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
        String albumColumn      = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
        String yearColumn       = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            String pendingStatus = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING;
            values.put(pendingStatus, 1);
            resolver.update(musicUri, values, null, null);
            values.put(pendingStatus, 0);
        }

        values.put(titleColumn, title);
        values.put(artistColumn, artist);
        values.put(albumColumn, album);
        values.put(yearColumn, year);
        Log.d(TAG,"values: "+values);
        resolver.update(musicUri, values, null, null);

        Log.d(TAG,"resolver update: "+ resolver.update(musicUri, values, null, null));

        String SONG_TITLE    = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
        String SONG_ARTIST   = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
        String SONG_ALBUM    = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
        String SONG_YEAR     = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
        String IS_PENDING    = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING;
        String SONG_IS_MUSIC = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC;

        String[] songColumns = {
                SONG_TITLE,
                SONG_ARTIST,
                SONG_ALBUM,
                SONG_YEAR,
                IS_PENDING
        };

        String selection = SONG_IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, songColumns, selection, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Log.d(TAG,"song title: "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_TITLE)));
                Log.d(TAG,"song artist: "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ARTIST)));
                Log.d(TAG,"song album: "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUM)));
                Log.d(TAG,"song year: "+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_YEAR)));
                Log.d(TAG, "isPending: "+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(IS_PENDING)));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        /*
        ContentValues valuesAlbum = new ContentValues();
        valuesAlbum.put(albumIdColumn, albumId);
        valuesAlbum.put(albumDataColumn, file_path);

        resolver.delete(albumArtUri, null,null);
        resolver.insert(sArtworkUri, valuesAlbum);
         */

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught when changing MP3 tags!", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
musicUri: content://media/external/audio/media/47
values: artist=test year=2023 album=test title=test is_pending=0
resolver update: 1
song title: Bruno Mars - The Lazy Song
song artist: <unknown>
song album: Music
song year: 0
isPending: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you need doing something with `MediaStore.createWriteRequest` and `startIntentSenderForResult` to request permission from user, then deal in `onActivityResult`